# php fopen disabled - alternative needed

Tags: php, fopen

My web host just disabled fopen()

My script used to open and write to a text file on the server, but no longer can.

Is there an alternative function to fopen?

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to do it with [fsockopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php).
For me this worked:

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Don't forget to change the host and request parameter

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of.  But it's a perfectly safe function to use on shared hosting (BUT ONLY IF the environment is set up right), so if your host disabled it for security reasons they're security noobs and you should find a new host.

Find a new one anyways

Answer (score 2):

I don't think [cURL](http://php.net/curl) requires [`allow_url_fopen`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) to be enabled. However, the cURL extension must be installed. Use [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo) to check if it's installed.

It's a little more advanced than your normal `fopen()` or `file_get_contents()` but it's definitely an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If it's available you could probably replicate your script with cURL

https://www.php.net/cURL